# Find matching objects on Sequelize backend query

Tags: sql, express, mariadb, sequelize.js

we are working on a MariaDB backend with Sequelize and Express, and we need to find every matching object that contains an uncomplete string, I mean, if somebody searches `JO` and the database entry is `JO2019` this is supposed to be listed, and everything that contains `JO`, but it's not. We've tried [OP.like], but it's not returning the data.

Thanks in advance, any help is accepted.

```html
accidents_basics.trobar = async (req, res) => {
 const nep_cercat = req.query.nep;
  const data = await Accident.findAll({
    where: {nep: nep_cercat},
    
  })
  const data1 = await AccidentDatos.findAll({
 where: {nep:{ [Op.Like]: nep_cercat},}

  })  
  .then( function(data){
    return data;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return error;
  })
  res.status(200).json({
    success:true,
    message:"Se han encontrado los datos!",
    data:data, data1, nep_cercat
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to use the regex behaviour instead of the app:

```
  const data1 = await AccidentDatos.findAll({
    where: {nep:{ [Op.regexp]: nep_cercat},}
  })
```

If you don't inlude '%' inside 'like' research, you maybe cannot have the goog results...